# Gather digit from twilio call and send to webhook

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, twilio, asp.net-core-webapi, twilio-api

I need to implement a way for call recipients to unsubscribe from calls made from my system. To do this, I added a line in my script that says "press 9 if you no longer wish to receive these calls.". When the recipient presses 9, I would like for the recipients number and digit pressed to be sent to my REST api so that I can remove them from my system. I attempted to accomplish this with the code below but I cannot get a response to be sent to Request bin. What am I doing wrong?

```
var twiml = new VoiceResponse();
            var gather = new Gather(input: "dtmf", action: new Uri("https://requestb.in/17lr5671"), method: "POST",
                timeout: 5, finishOnKey: "9", numDigits: 1);
            gather.Say(script, Say.VoiceEnum.Woman);
            twiml.Append(gather);
            return new TwiMLResult(twiml);
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this. The finishOnKey setting was causing the call to end and not pick up the digit. Instead, I removed the finishOnKey setting and left the numDigits parameter set to 1. This way, no matter what digit the recipient presses, the call will end and send the digits to my API. Below is the updated code:

```
var twiml = new VoiceResponse();
        var gather = new Gather(input: "dtmf", action: new Uri("https://requestb.in/17lr5671"), method: "POST",
            timeout: 5, numDigits: 1);
        gather.Say(script, Say.VoiceEnum.Woman);
        twiml.Append(gather);
        return new TwiMLResult(twiml);
```